# mesh editing, sculpting not on first frame?

Tags: modeling

Im trying to edit my mesh but I've already animated it . When I view the mesh its not perpendicular to the world grid or transform tools.Am I supposed to only edit the mesh when it is at world origin and aligned with the grid, or is there a way to temporarily align the grid  and transform tools ?

Am I supposed to only edit mesh when it is at origin ? (especially if im editing symmetry)

[image]

Comment: Hello, you don't tell enough, when you  say that you've animated your mesh, how is it animated?

Comment: thnks moonbots. what i mean is ive transformed my object away from the origin, so, as in picture above it lies off axis of the grid and all the views.  I dont know how to view the object exactly head-on or above, etc when it is not at origin.-

Comment: in that case perhaps the best is to realign the mesh on the local axis? How does the local axis look like?

Comment: thks. How does 'local look'? It looks fine, I guess. Not sure what you mean, and I dont see any way to add another screen grab to this thread ...

What Im asking is - if I am sculpting should I be sculpting only when object is at origin so that my grids and view are aligned and not complicated by being askew, etc ? does that make sense ?
Look at above- that is top view (7), but my head object is diagonal to the grid and view. how can i look at the object top view (local axes aligned) ? It doesnt matter if im looking at local axis- the view is aligned with global axes.

Comment: If the origin is aligned with the axis of your character, you don't care if it's not aligned with the Global axis, except you can't see frontal views with 1, 3 or  7, if the origin is not aligned with the axis of your character, you should better realign it, but it's impossible to say with this picture only

Comment: so basically every tutorial Ive seen so far is based on an object sculpted at origin. Should I be only sculpting at origin, before i've begun animating away from origin ? I

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "sculpting at origin", if you mean that the object needs to have its location, rotation and scale reset, no, you don't need